# Get real position inside drag event

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, xamarin

I use drag for imageview :

```
case MotionEventActions.Down:

                    ClipData data = ClipData.NewPlainText ("letter", l.ToString ());
                    MyDragShadowBuilder my_shadown_screen = new MyDragShadowBuilder (imageView);
                    imageView.StartDrag (data, my_shadown_screen, null, 0);
                    break;
```

and handle drag event with HandleDrag, I need to get location of pointer when the action will end, but it returns different values.
this is how I try to get location:

```
case DragAction.Exited:
            x = evt.GetX ();
            y = evt.GetY ();
            Log.Debug ("get from exited", x.ToString () + " - " + y.ToString ());
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        case DragAction.Location:
            x = evt.GetX ();
            y = evt.GetY ();
            Log.Debug ("get from location", x.ToString () + " - " + y.ToString ());
            break;
```

this is real location of point :
[image]
and this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation:

> The getX() and getY() methods supply the X and Y position of of the drag point within the View object's bounding box.

In this case you need to get the view's location where the event was fired, then add to it the result of getX() and getY(). I'm not sure, but maybe there's also needed to subtract half of the width and height of the dragged view